# ForLoop VBA Coding Hardcoded values

Tags: excel, vba

Values Entered into Excel

```
A2 =4
A3 = 2500

C2= 15
D2= 30
E2 =35
F2= 40
```

Values to Populate:
I want to populate cells starting in cell C5 through Cells [C5 + (value in A2)] with the value in A3
So in this example C5 through F5 with the value in A3 (2500)

I want to populate cells starting in C6 through Cells [C6 + value in A2) with the corresponding cell values in (C2  + value in A2)
so in this example C6 = C2, D6 = D2, E6 = E2, F6 = F2

You only populate as many columns across as the number in A2

[image]

Comment: use `Resize()`: `ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Resize(1,ActiveSheet.Range("A2")).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A3")`

Comment: And `ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Resize(1,ActiveSheet.Range("A2")).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Resize(1,ActiveSheet.Range("A2")).Value`

Comment: This is amazing and works perfectly!  I was trying to do a loop and this is much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: What if the value in A2 was zero, how would you get it to not error out?